# How Would I create this sequence in the LLVM builder framework?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am learning LLVM basics. I am trying to get into the builder framework and have set up the module, a function header etc, but I have not been able yet to figure out a way to create a simple sequence like this in builder:

```
%0 = 41
%1 = add i32 42, %0
```

Meaning how can I use the pseudo register notation through the builder framework?

I have tried to create a plus instruction based on two constants. The core line I'm using to generate the (integer) addition is:

```
    Value *L = (Value *)m_left->Create_LLVM(  );
    Value *R = (Value *)m_right->Create_LLVM();
    if ( L == 0 || R == 0 ) return 0;

    llvm::Value *p_instruction =  Get_Builder().CreateAdd( L, R, "addtmp" );
```

This contains lots of my own functions but I guess the basics is clear. I get a Value pointer for the left and right operands which are both constants and then create an add operation with the builder framwork. Again the module and builder are set up correctly, when I call dump() I see all the other stuff I do, but this line above does not create any IR code.

I would expect it co create something like

```
%4 = add i32 %3, %2
```

or something similar. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about the way operations are to be constructed with the builder or is it just some small oversight of some detail?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hard to say what you are doing wrong without the fancy `Create_LLVM()` functions but in general for adding two constants:

You have to create 2 `ConstantInt`:

```
const auto& ctx = getGlobalContext(); // just your LLVMContext
auto* L = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(ctx), 41);
auto* R = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(ctx), 42);
const auto& builder = Get_Builder();
builder.Insert(L);  // just a no-op in standard builder impl
builder.Insert(R);  // just a no-op in standard builder impl
builder.CreateAdd(L, R, "addtmp");
```

You should get:

```
%addtmp = add i32 41, i32 42;
```

You said that your builder is set up correctly, so it will add the `add` at the end of the **`BasicBlock`** it currently operates on. And I assume you have allready created a `Function` with at least one `BasicBlock`.

**Edit:** 
What will bring give you an add instruction in any way is to create it just calling the C++ API without the builder:

```
BinaryOperator* add = BinaryOperator::Create(BinaryOps::Add, L, R, "addtmp", BB);
```

where BB is the current `BasicBlock`.

To get something more sophisticated (adding to variables) the canonical way is this:

At first you need some memory. The `AllocaInst` allocates memory on the stack:

You can use the builder for this:

```
auto* A = builder.CreateAlloca (Type::getInt32Ty(ctx), nullptr, "a");
auto* B = builder.CreateAlloca (Type::getInt32Ty(ctx), nullptr, "b");
```

For simplicity I'll just take the constants from above and store them in A and B. 
To store values we need `StoreInst`:

```
builder.CreateStore (L, A, /*isVolatile=*/false);
builder.CreateStore (R, B, /*isVolatile=*/false);
```

For the addition we load the value from memory to a register using `LoadInst`:

```
auto* addLHS = builder.CreateLoad(A);
auto* addRHS = builder.CreateLoad(B);
```

Finally the addition as above:
    auto* add = builder.CreateAdd(addLHS, addRHS , "add");

And with the pointer to add you can go on, e.g., returning it or storing it to another variable.

The IR should look like this:

```
define i32 foo() {
entry:
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 41, i32* %a, align 4
  store i32 42, i32* %b, align 4
  %0 = load i32* %a, align 4
  %1 = load i32* %b, align 4
  %add = add i32 %0, %1
  ret i32 %add
}
```

Comment: After another day of experimenting I got somewhat farther and I realize that the builder now simply creates a return statement with the constant value without actually performing the addition, which vexed me at first because I was not expecting that without an explicit request for optimization, but probably that sort of thing is trivial for LLVM and goes without saying.

Comment: My main problem is now the first one though. I am not able to actually store a value in a variable, In fact I have not yet found any Value derived class that resembles a variable, so I assume, to handle variables in a way that is compatible with the basic tutorials about the IR, there must be some complex way to handle it that is somehow obfuscated and not easily found.

Comment: The builder has a constant folder that performs constant folding just during IR generation and this will most likely be the reason why you see such an optimization without optimizer passes.

Comment: Yes I figured that, it's just confusing when you dont expect it. Any hint on how I can go about store values in a variable? That's really my main obstacle

Comment: I see. Well finally things are beginning to get clearer, thanks a lot for the explanation. I was under the impression that I should be able to create sequences of variables through sequences like %0 = 42 without allocating storage first, as is in the pure IR code examples. So far I have not seen any way to do this and your answer seems to indicate that there is no way of doing that in the builder. I have to study the example some more to let it sink in, but I'm beginning to see clearer now, thanks.

Comment: The value for 'R' in the first code example should be 42 instead of 41.